# php obj properites accessilibty not writtable outside of class but readable outside of class

Tags: php

I do not want to make the properties of class example accessible only to it's children, but I want the children to be able to change them apart from the initial __construct. This is how I have things set up at the moment. Can I be doing this a better way?

```
class example{
    private $x
    protected function __construct($x){
        setX($x);
    }
    private function setX($x){
        $this->x = $x;
    }
    protected function getX{
        return $this->x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand, do you want a subclass to access the value of a property, but not be able to set them, except for in the constructor? If that's the case then this is the best way (although you probably want your constructor to be public right?) - by overriding the constructor method.

Comment: I want my constructor only to be accessibly through the subclasses in which case would setting it as public would be accessible to thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do I understand correctly that you only want $x to be readable (but not editable) by it's children?

Then yes your class definition looks alright (albeit the syntax errors).

Children cannot access private members, only protected (and public, durhur).

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to use that getter/setter outside the function, like this?

```
$a = new Example(5);
$a->setX(25);

echo $a->getX();
```

If yes, you need to set them two to public functions:

```
class Example{
    private $x
    protected function __construct($x){
        setX($x);
    }
    public function setX($x){
        $this->x = $x;
    }
    public function getX{
        return $this->x;
    }
}
```

PS.: It's a good pratice to capitalize your class names.

Comment: I want the getter/setters to be used only inside subclasses so wouldn't protected by the way to go?